# Is there a word that means "to hate beauty"?

Tags: meaning

For example, to love beauty is called "philocaly". Does this have an opposite?

Comment: Note that *philocaly* is not merely a very rare word, it is a technical term proper to philosophy and theology, and should probably not be used as a synonym of *aesthete*. *Calophile* and *calophilic* (which would yield *calophily*) had a minor currency in French LitCrit of the early part of the last century and appears to be employed a good deal in contemporary Romanian art criticism.

Answer (score 4):

A few sources ([1](http://www.kokogiak.com/logolepsy/ow_m.html#misoscopist), [2](http://home.comcast.net/~wwftd/mno.htm#misoscopist)) list ***misoscopist***:

> *n*. - a hater of beauty; a recluse

I suppose then the hate of beauty would be ***misoscopism*** or possibly ***misoscopy***.

Comment: I don't know Greek, and I just saw this ("the opposite of philosophy (the love of reason) is hatred of reasoning (misology)") on a [philosophy website](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:yk0sip1Q1goJ:www.roangelo.net/logwitt/philosophy-origin.html+&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=tw), & that your first & second links say "misosophy
= hatred of wisdom", so I wonder whether _misocaly_ might also be possible.

Comment: @BillFranke See my Comment to the previous answer. Great minds ...

Answer (score 1):

I propose *misocalia*, from *misogyny*.

Comment: I should have said misocallia. Sorry.

Comment: No need to comment, just edit your answer.

Comment: @brsnain: Both *misocalia* and *misocallia* are possible. But it so happens that *philocalia* was actually in use in Ancient Greek, so the variant with one l is probably preferable. And the ending *-ly* is commonly used in English, as in the existing word *philocaly*, so *misocaly* is probably the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

> Suffixes with the common part -phil- (-phile, -philia, -philic) are used to specify some kind of attraction or affinity to something, in particular the love or obsession with something. *They are antonymic to suffixes -phob-*.
>
> Phil- (philo-) may also be used as a prefix with a similar meaning.

<sup>Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-phil-</sup>

**Calophobe** would be the antonym of philocaly, meaning to dislike, or hate, beauty.

Comment: phobe:(n) [combining form] indicating a person or thing that fears or hates (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-phobe)

Comment: Does it have a same meaning for both suffix and prefix form?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, *phob-* is not used as a prefix in English. Through 1987, *OED 1* lists only one instance, *phobanthropy*, which it labels a nonce-word (as is acknowledged in the single quotation). The prefix antonymic to *phil(o)-* is *mis(o)-*; consider, for instance *philanthropy/misanthropy*, *philogyny/misogyny*, *philology/misology*. The antonym to *philocaly* would then be *misocaly*.

Comment: @StoneyB: Yes, it works. :-)