# Pulchraphilia or Pulchriphilia?

Tags: orthography, latin

'Pulchraphilia' or 'Pulchriphilia' or 'Pulchrophilia'? Does anybody know what the spelling of such a word would be? Should I take the cue from the spelling of pulchritude and use an *i*, or is an *a* correct?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. It is expected that a spelling question will be researched before asking.you should show what you have done to get an answe before asking here. Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be mixing Latin and Greek roots.

Comment: @J.Taylor What an inane response. How do you know whether I've researched it or not? Also, this is the first time I've ever used this site, so you given me a terrible impression of it.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod Any help or are you just a pedant?

Comment: If you must go with a linguistic bastard of a formation the I would say use the i- "pulchri" is the combining form.

Comment: Nevermind. You guys aren't very helpful, but thanks for the advice about creating a 'linguistic bastard'. Anyway, I found the answers I'm looking for here: http://latindiscussion.com/forum/latin/pulchraphilia-or-pulchriphilia.29264

Comment: @Jesse Waugh ....you had not demonstrated any research, that is why my post. You have now, seemingly, accomplished the fact on your own. That is the point. The question was not required. I regret  your impression of my post, but, anything you can reasonably acquire on your own should be so acquired.Most in this community do not care to perform basic research for posters..There is much to be learned here, much of it we need to get on our own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Calophilia* is properly formed, from Greek *kalos* "beautiful" and *phil-* "like/love". But Greek has the odd habit of often creating compound nouns with the minor element (here the substantivised adjective) at the end, which is not normal in Latin or English, as in *philanthropy*, *misogyny* or *hippopotamus*. The word *[**philocaly**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/philocaly)* exists in English, and it exemplifies this little Greek oddity. The word *[philokalia](http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=lsj&lang=el&word=filokali%2Fa&filter=CUTF8)* already existed in Ancient Greek, "love of the beautiful". So it has an impeccable pedigree. All this makes *philocaly* caliston ("most beautiful") in the eyes of philocalists and pedants alike.

If it is necessary to use the Latin root *pulchr*-, then it would be *pulchriphilia*. But the Romans were very unlikely to create compound nouns like this; they normally just used two words, as in *amor pulchri* "love of the beautiful". Secondly, hybrid Graeco-Latin compounds are generally not preferred.

P.S. See also this question: [Is there a word that means “to hate beauty”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112904/is-there-a-word-that-means-to-hate-beauty).

(P.P.S. I apologize for the grumpiness of some of my colleagues. That's just what this site is known for: it's not you.)

Comment: Thanks very much for the *beautiful* answer! - this clarifies it for me. I think I'll use 'philokalia' for common usage, and 'calophilia' for more poetic uses, as it seems the most beautiful to me.

Comment: @JesseWaugh: By all means, choose whatever suits you! As long as you know that Greek k is normally used in English: instead, we convert Greek into Latin, and only then adapt it into English. So Greek *philokalia* will become *philocalia* in Latin. Then English can either keep it at *philocalia*, or Anglicise it into *philocaly* (the most traditional way). P.S. If you like this answer, you could additionally give it an up-vote (press the up arrow).

Comment: Thanks! I tried to upvote it but it won’t met me - I have to have more than 15 points or something.

Comment: Obviously I love the answer. It is the kind of word I was trying to nudge the OP towards.

Comment: @JesseWaugh: Ah, I see! Well, thanks for trying, hehe.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod: I figured. Too bad the question only has my up-vote.

Comment: I upvoted the question because it led to a great answer.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod: Gracias!